# Floor joist notching - where is the middle third

Tags: plumbing, framing, engineering

I have a house with 24' 2x8 floor joists. At the center of the span, they rest on a perpendicular beam 44' long which is supported by steel posts. I need to run two 3/4" PEX heating lines through the joists.

Is the middle third of the span (the no notch zone) the center 8' of the 24' span, or does the support beam in the middle bearing the load effectively divide the 24' into two 12' load bearing spans, with two no notch zones in the middle 4' of those spans?

Also, how close together can the two 3/4" notches be, and if I chose to bore holes instead, how close together can they be?

Comment: I changed `2 3/4" holes` to `two 3/4" holes` to help clarify between quantity and size, since there was some confusion in the answers.

Answer (score 3):

Making notches and holes that are 2 3/4" inches wide / diameter is far from optimal for a small 2x8 joist. After all a 2x8 joist is only a 7 1/2" or 7 3/4" depth from top to bottom (depending upon how old they are).

If it were me wanting to maintain the integrity of the floor on those joists I would strongly encourage hanging the 2 3/4" heating lines below the joists and if they need to be covered for aesthetic reasons then enclose them in a built soffit.

Comment: OP here: To clarify, these are two 3/4" holes near each other to run 3/4" PEX, NOT the size 2 3/4". The PEX size is 3/4".

Answer (score 3):

Boring 3/4" to 1" (depending on the actual OD of your pipe) holes in the middle (top to bottom) third of your joists would be the least structural impact on your joists. Holes should be separated by 2" of wood (not 2" center to center - 2" edge to edge) and should also be at least 2" from the top or bottom edge.

Notches have **much greater structural impact** than correctly located holes. Correctly located holes are not forbidden in the center 1/3. In your case, the center 1/3 (end-to-end) would be the 4 feet centered in the span between supports. If you choose to make notches anyway, they should not be square-edged.

Comment: This is the key.  Holes along the center line of a beam/joist has little impact on the load carrying capacity of that member since the center is under very little stress (tension or compression).

Comment: It's worth emphasizing that **no notch is in the middle third**. Period. The middle third exists both with respect to length _and_ height. You need to consider each axis, and a notch is, by definition, at the edge.

Comment: In fact, the limitation on notch **depth** is considerably **more stringent** than 1/3, at D/6